# C#: How do I cast within a class to the template type?

Tags: c#, templates, casting

First off, I'm new to C#, coming from C/C++, and I'm finding a lot of annoyances in the language implementation.

What I'm trying to do: create a generic field for a "register".  The field will use the same type for internal data as the register size.  So a 32-bit register will have only 32-bit unsigned internal data.

As part of error checking that the values passed to the field constructor are valid, I'm using `is` to determine the max number of bits.

```
public class Field<T>
{
  private t mask;
  public Field( T size, T position )
  {
    T maxBits = mask is UInt32 ? 32: mask is UInt64 ? 64 : 0;
  }
}
```

> Program.cs: error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'T'

So I changed the offending line:

```
T maxBits = mask is UInt32 ? (T)32: mask is UInt64 ? (T)64 : (T)0;
```

and I get the same error, only without the word "implicitly".

How does one cast to type T within a template class in C#?  After an hour of internet searching I've realized: it should NOT be this hard.

---

UPDATE:
Thanks for the comments Caius Jard & Clemens.

I am plagued by two things. First, I read a blog where the author said "Generics and Templates are the same to me."  Well, maybe to the writer; but no, they're not! This fed my faulty assumption of compile-time evaluation of the not-a-template, instead of runtime evaluation of the generic.

So I read a little bit more from the MS docs about Generics, and what I want to do with them isn't what they're meant to do.  And that explains all of the other compilation errors I'm getting, and let's me know that there isn't a way to fix it.  (Errors around simple math like left shifting, comparisons, etc).

Thanks for the schooling!

As far as the annoyance - I don't think I'll stop being annoyed, I'll just learn to deal with it.  When attempting to write a PowerShell script after using Bash for years, that's what happened.  I feel like MS *almost* got it right, but not quite.  And it just further validates my *opinion* that everything MS is mediocre at best.  But the world runs on MS, so...  I'll just sit and be a grumpy Linux bear while I work on this MS application.  LOL

Comment: *I'm finding a lot of annoyances in the language implementation* - they ought to go away as soon as you cease assuming that because both languages start with the letter C, the things you're used to from one will work in the other. C# doesn't have templates; generics are different things

Comment: You probably meant `int maxBits`

Comment: T is a generic type known only at runtime. Casting an int to an unknown type does not work. As mentioned  above, making maxBits of type int should do the trick for the cast. Nevertheless I assume you are getting something wrong. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because `T` can be many different types. For example, you could declare

```cs
var field = new Field<HttpClient>(new HttpClient(), new HttpClient());
```

That would make the assignment in the constructor equivalent to

```cs
HttpClient maxBits = mask is UInt32 
    ? (HttpClient)32 
    : mask is UInt64 ? (HttpClient)64 : (HttpClient)0;
```

Obviously this doesn't make sense. You can't assign a value of 32 to a variable of type `HttpClient`.

The compiler has no way of knowing what the runtime type of `T` is, which means that it could be invalid for the casts you're attempting. The job of the compiler is find potential issues like this before you run the code so that you don't get runtime errors when you run the code. It's the same reason why `int x = "Hello";` won't compile.

There are [generic constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) which tell the compiler more about the type of `T`. But there is no generic constraint which says that `T` will only be `UInt32` or `UInt64`. So you'll need a different solution to the problem.

---

One option might be to define an `enum` that contains only the values you want to allow, like

```cs
public enum FieldBits // I'm guessing - I don't know if this
{                     // makes sense for what you're trying to do.
    Zero = 0          // It's just to give you an idea.
    ThirtyTwo = 32,
    SixtyFour = 64
}
```

If you pass this enum to your constructor then the class knows which one of these values to use, and it's impossible to call the constructor without using one of these values. Then you can use that enum value to determine the value of `maxBits`.